# Sonar Cube "null pointer exception could be thrown" : False positive?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

I have a bug raised by sonar cube on following code :

```
private request = null;
try
{
request = createRequest(); // create Request
log.info(" Request created with details "+request.toString());
}
catch(...)
{
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

The bug is raised at log.info statement as it suggests to check request for NULL before using. But my doubt is in case I check it for null and if it is actually null, then I would like it to goto catch exception block, which anyhow it will go in case I dont check explicitly for NULL. So is it false positive?How can i handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a false positive. `request` can be null in your code so calling `toString` on it will cause the null pointer exception to be thrown.

If `createRequest` can return null then you should explicitly check for it rather than just rely on the log statement. Something like the following.

```
private request = null;
try
{
request = createRequest(); // create Request
if ( null == request ){
    throw new NullRequestException();
}
log.info(" Request created with details "+request.toString());
}
catch(...)
{
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

On a side note, I find catching `Exception` like you are doing in your snippet is generally a bad idea. I can't see enough of the context of your code to know if that is true in your case, but it's something that you should probably take a look at.

Comment: this is the code that is written by somebody and i am trying to remove sonar reported bugs.One thing is that if we throw NULLRequestException ,then also it will goto Exception's catch block and if i mistakenly tries to access null request's toString, still it will goto same Exception Block.I dont see why i should check explicitly for null unless until i need some specific behaviour in case of NULLPointerException??

Comment: That's why catching `Exception` is a bad idea.